# How can I use single and plural resource routes in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Consider the following resource route for posts and comments:

```
resources :posts do
    resources :comments
end
```

This produces URLs like `/posts/` and `/posts/34`

However, for the latter, is it possible to use the singular version, so that it simply reads as `/post/34`, whilst still keeping plural for `/posts/`?

Any guidance on how best to do this would be greatly appreciated - or if indeed this is a good idea or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always rename the `:path` and define a route for posts:

```
resources :posts, :path => "post"
get '/posts', to: "posts#index"
```

Comment: This works, but what if I need to link to posts and post in my view? What are the helpers needed for this? At the moment I am using <%= link_to "Posts", posts_path %> which now defaults to /post using your method.

Comment: Think I have figured this out - I simply swapped the order of the routes you specified above. Would you say this is good behavior?

Comment: Yeah, I think it's more elegant than messing with the [inflectors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-singular-form) which has consequences for the DB table name and the controller itself. With `:path` you just concern yourself with the routing layer.

Comment: I tried swapping them around and now creating a new post breaks, because it tried to load /posts. Any idea on getting around this? Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you restart your server. With `get` first before the `resources` line, I do get `/post/new` as expected when I try to create a new post.

Comment: I have restarted but the problem still occurs. I can get to /post/new - that's great, but when posting the form, it breaks, showing /posts

Comment: Leave them in the order I gave and it will work, since routes are matched in the order they are specified, so in your case the `get` being first breaks the POST to posts#create.

Comment: run `rake routes` to get a list of routes and associated url helpers